# Baseline mean by subject visits (SAS)

Tags: sql, sas, summary

I am attempting to calculate the baseline mean values at a specific visit. For example, if a subject does not have a specified visit, the baseline mean will be re-calculated omitting the subject.

Here is the data:

```
Subject            Visit              Value
001                Baseline           10
001                Visit 2            11
001                Visit 3            12
001                Visit 4            13
002                Baseline           11
002                Visit 2            12
002                Visit 4            13
002                Visit 5            14
003                Baseline           12
003                Visit 3            13
003                Visit 4            14
003                Visit 5            15
```

I'd like to obtain the following:

```
Visit             BaselineMean       VisitMean
Baseline          11                 11
Visit 2           10.5               11.5
Visit 3           11                 12.5
Visit 4           11                 13.3
Visit 5           11.5               14.5
```

Here is the table I have for the mean at each visit:

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select 
    visit, 
    mean(value) as meanValue
from have
group by visit;
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a join of two aggregates, one of which uses a self join on itself:

```
proc sql;
   CREATE TABLE want as 
   SELECT bagg.Visit, bagg.BaselineMean, vagg.VisitMean
   FROM 
     (SELECT t2.Visit, MEAN(t1.Value) AS BaselineMean
      FROM have t1
      INNER JOIN have t2
         ON t1.Subject = t2.Subject 
        AND t1.Visit = 'Baseline'
      GROUP BY t2.Visit) bagg

   INNER JOIN
     (SELECT Visit, MEAN(Value) AS VisitMean
      FROM have 
      GROUP BY Visit) vagg
   ON bagg.Visit = vagg.Visit;
quit;
```

## <kbd>[SQL Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cerCiKcP6E99u8CCaJpJmz/0)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

first creat a table to have baseline value for each subject as follows:

```
proc sql;
create table baseline as 
    select distinct subject, value
        from t1
    where visit = 'Baseline'
;
```

then augment the main table with the baseline value. Note that coalesce is used in case there is no baseline record for a subject:

```
proc sql;
    create table inter as 
        select t1.*m, coalesce(b.value, 0) as b_val 
            from t1 left join baseline b  
                on t1.subject = b.subject
;
quit;
```

finally calculate the mean values for baseline and visits as follows:

```
  proc sql;
        select visit, mean(b_val) as BaselineMean, mean(value) as visitMean
            from inter 
    group by visit
;
quit;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can compute the aggregate statistics over a sub-select that itself uses a correlated sub-query which selects the subjects baseline value.

```
proc sql;
  create table want as
  select 
    visit
  , mean(baseline) as baselinemean format=5.1
  , mean(value) as visitmean       format=5.1
  from 
    ( select 
        visit
      , value
      , ( select value 
          from have as inner 
          where inner.subject = outer.subject 
            and inner.visit='Baseline'
        ) as baseline
      from have as outer
    )
  group by visit
  ;
quit;
```